# Como fazer um sistema de login?

Tags: html

eu queria saber como faço para criar um sistema de login em html! ou se for necessário usar outra linguagem junto pode falar tambem. sou iniciante e peço que vc faça uma parte dizendo quais comandos é para usar e depois dizer a resposta em si pois gostaria de tentar fazer sozinho mas eu n se os comandos

obrigado desde já, ser programador é meu sonho <3

Comment: Obs: O sistema que eu peço não precisa ter banco de dados . eu so quero um sistema em que se coloque o nome e senha e acontecer algo.

Comment: Se estiver utilizando Apache para servir sua página, veja como criar autenticação `Basic`, com o `.htaccess`.